# Unable to partition varchar field storing numeric value with leading 0 in postgres

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I am using Postgres 13.9

Below is the table structure:-

```
create table t5
(
id varchar(3), --using id as varchar since I want to retain leading 0. 
fname varchar
)partition by range (id);

create table t5_a partition of t5 for values from (001) to (010);
create table t5_b partition of t5 for values from (010) to (020);
create table t5_c partition of t5 for values from (020) to (030);
```

If I try to insert below

```
insert into t5 values('007', 'Tom');
```

It throws below error:-

```
Error: no partition of relation "t5" found for row
```

Comment: To me, this looks like a bug in PostgreSQL: You shouldn't be able to create a partition based on an integer when the column is a varchar. And a range doesn't look like a good match for a varchar anyway, highly dependent on character encoding, ICU, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added single quote in ranges and I am able to insert data now:-

```
create table t5_a partition of t5 for values from ('001') to ('010');
create table t5_b partition of t5 for values from ('010') to ('020');
create table t5_c partition of t5 for values from ('020') to ('030');

insert into t5 values('007', 'Tom');
```

However, one thing to note is, if you try to insert data by passing only 7 instead of '007', it will throw an error.